# Why DISTINCT is faster than GROUP BY/FOREACH in Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have no idea why DISTINCT is faster than GROUP BY/FOREACH in Pig, they should be same in MapReduce Framework, but refer to:

```
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#distinct
```

The Pig wiki says that "To extract unique values from a column in a relation you can use DISTINCT or GROUP BY/GENERATE. DISTINCT is the preferred method; it is faster and more efficient."

Why? are the implement in different ways?

Answer (score 3):

Output of distinct  is a relation which contains only columns you do distinct on, thus Map jobs output only values for specified columns as keys and combiners minimize map spill output further causing less input for the Reducer.
Output of Group By is a "group" key tuple and a Bag which contains all of the tuples that have the same group key with all of the columns of the original relation, thus combiners are not used and outputs of the Map stage are larger and reducers have more inputs. Pig could do some optimizations, but they are not guarantied.